# Sum of shopping list price in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following DB structure:

```
[Table `lists`] 
one has many [Table `lists_positions`] 
  one has one [Table `products`] 
    many has many through [Table `products_prices_tables`] [Table `prices_tables`] 
      has many [Table `prices`]
```

Is there any possibility to obtain sum of all products' prices in all existing lists in the database?

I have tried with:

```
SELECT x.list_id AS id, x.modified_on AS modified_on, ROUND(SUM(x.sum_price), 2) AS cart_price
FROM (
    SELECT list_id, modified_on, AVG(y.price_weight) AS sum_price
    FROM (
        SELECT l.id AS list_id, l.modified_on AS modified_on, pr.price_weight AS price_weight
        FROM `lists_positions` lp
        INNER JOIN `lists` l ON l.id = lp.list_id
        INNER JOIN `products` p ON p.id = lp.product_id
        LEFT JOIN `products_prices_tables` ppt ON ppt.product_id = p.id 
        LEFT JOIN `prices_tables` pt ON pt.id = ppt.price_table_id 
        LEFT JOIN `prices` pr ON pr.price_table_id = pt.id
        GROUP BY l.id
    ) y
    GROUP BY y.list_id
) x
GROUP BY x.list_id
```

but it does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This seems to work for me:

```
SELECT modified_on, ROUND(SUM(y.price_weight), 2) AS sum_price
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(l.modified_on) AS modified_on, 
    (AVG(pr.price_weight) * lp.amount) AS price_weight
    FROM `lists_positions` lp
    INNER JOIN `lists` l ON l.id = lp.list_id
    INNER JOIN `products` p ON p.id = lp.product_id
    INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.id = l.user_id
    INNER JOIN `products_prices_tables` ppt ON ppt.product_id = p.id 
    INNER JOIN `prices_tables` pt ON pt.id = ppt.price_table_id 
    INNER JOIN `prices` pr ON pr.price_table_id = pt.id
    WHERE (
    (:sexCriteria) AND (:rangeCriteria)
    ) GROUP BY lp.id
) y
GROUP BY y.modified_on
```

Comment: Your query would return an error in most databases...but this is one of those cases that MySQL likes to do the wrong thing and not return an error.  Every field in the select line that isn't in the group by line should be an aggregate.  For each group of l.id, you need to give it logic as far as which l.modified_on field to bring back (mysql is just randomly returning one for now)

Comment: instead of doing multiple subqueries inside one another try inserting subquery info into temp tables.  It will be more code but it will be neater and a bit easier to understand

Comment: @Twelfth could you tell me more about what I am doing wrong with select line? What does "Every field in the select line that isn't in the group by line should be an aggregate." mean? Could you provide me an example?

Comment: lets say you have 5 records with the same l.id on them, each with a different price and a (i assume) different modified_on date.  You want the rows to add the prices for each l.id, however there is no logic to say which modified_on date it should choose.  As your query sits, you'll end up with a random one (kinda random) that MySQL brings up while any other database would return an error saying you need to be choosing one.  If you want the most recent date of all 5 records for that l.id, max(date) will give you that

Comment: @Twelfth ok, now I understand, thank you. Though, now I group by modified_on and summing second column (publicly) so I think it is okay.